# Cannot interpret maldet results

Tags: malware, antimalware

After executing `sudo maldet -a /`

LMD provides the following report:

```
HOST:      foo.bar.baz
SCAN ID:   210117-2223.1145531
STARTED:   Jan 17 2021 22:23:26 +0000
COMPLETED: Jan 18 2021 22:01:12 +0000
ELAPSED:   85066s [find: 42s]

PATH:          /
TOTAL FILES:   579780
TOTAL HITS:    2
TOTAL CLEANED: 0

WARNING: Automatic quarantine is currently disabled, detected threats are still accessible to users!
To enable, set quarantine_hits=1 and/or to quarantine hits from this scan run:
/usr/local/sbin/maldet -q 210117-2223.1145531

FILE HIT LIST:
{HEX}php.cmdshell.antichat.201 : /home/foo/maldetect-1.6.4/files/sigs/rfxn.yara
{HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452 : /home/foo/maldetect-1.6.4/files/clean/gzbase64.inject.unclassed
===============================================
Linux Malware Detect v1.6.4 < proj@rfxn.com >
```

I struggle to interpret the results of the two hits. Is it in the home directory and what does HEX mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the README from maldetect:

> Let us assume for a moment we have malware that we want to clean and
> it trips with the signature "{HEX}php.cmdshell.r57.89". The actual
> signature string in this is "php.cmdshell.r57", the "{HEX}" just
> defines the format and ".89" is the variant number.

"format" in this will be either MD5 or HEX, the two types of maldetect signature.  Quoting again, "*The signatures that LMD uses are MD5 file hashes and HEX
pattern matches...*"

The two files that had 'hits' were both part of the maldetect distribution that foo unpacked under their home directory:

`/home/foo/maldetect-1.6.4/files/sigs/rfxn.yara` is a [Yara](https://virustotal.github.io/yara/) signature file.  It must contain a string that matches malicious software, but which also matches the tests that maldetect runs.  It is not actually malicious.

`/home/foo/maldetect-1.6.4/files/clean/gzbase64.inject.unclassed` is a cleaner file, which contains malicious strings to be matched and erased from infected files.  Again, it contains a string which matches a test that maldetect runs, but it isn't actually malicious.

The moral of this story is: don't scan the scanner directory.  Here's someone else with [the same problem](https://serverfault.com/q/840052/279074).